# How do I controll a NextUI Autocomplete Component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, nextui

I'm following the instructions from the "Controlled" section [here](https://nextui.org/docs/components/autocomplete). However, the selected key that I pass through is not being selected. I am just taking the value the component passes to `onSelectionChange` and using it unchanged for the `selectedKey` property.

I've noticed that for the similar `Select` component, this strategy does work, and also the value of `selectedKey` in `onSelectionChange` is not a `String`, but rather a `Set`. It seems to me that these two `selectedKey` values should both be of the same type, and that ideally they would both work as `String` values so that I could easily set an initial value

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any advice on how I might get this to work?